# Create COM-object on server in C#: ERROR: 80070776

Tags: c#, .net, com, windows-server-2008

Trying to create `COM`-object on server.

code is:

```
var myGuid = new Guid("530A1815-820C-11D3-BBB7-008048DE406A"); 
var myType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myGuid, some_ip, true); 
ITInfoServer infsrv = (ITInfoServer)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
// infsrv.callSomeMethod (....);
```

getting the error:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {530A1815-820C-11D3-BBB7-008048DE406A} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80070776.

Comment: 0x80070776 = OR_INVALID_OXID: "The object exporter specified was not found."

Comment: @Rup, thanks. "The object exporter specified was not found." - what does it mean?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, sorry. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc226948.aspx) makes it sound like a DCOM error: maybe your machine is attempting to remote to another machine to get the COM object but the other machine doesn't have the object configured to serve it to you?

Comment: Rup is right, this is a low-level RPC error probably associated with the proxy or stub.  Error reporting like this is what made Java big.

Comment: @VextoR, this error is often the result of invalid network configuration.  Some ports are closed or traffic routed to the wrong server and so on. What kind of object are you trying to instantiate? Is it supposed to be created remotely? Try to investingate on this questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like network problem that preventing from server to use the COM objects,
Can you try adding the server to your hosts file?

http://www.yusufozturk.info/windows-server/wmi-error-80070776-the-object-exporter-specified-was-not-found.html

http://www.awesomes.net/?p=28

Comment: "_Can you try adding the server to your hosts file?_" - this helped